# How can I unit test a 64-bit .NET 4.7 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-test-runner, visualstudio.testtools

I first got a BadImageFormatException in my test project and after some research it seemed that it was caused because the test project had a AnyCPU build, while the project I want to test had a 64-bit build. After changing my test project to 64 bit the tests stopped working all together. Their icons stays the blue circle with exclamation point after I select run all and when I select one it just show the source file and line number of the test.

I'm using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting for unit testing.

How can I get my test project to work?

I even threw it away and made a completely new test project and that still got the same error.

Comment: it must work with no issues, can you set everything to Any CPU and try again?

Comment: I can't change the original project's build, due to a depency that breaks it if it's not building 64-bit

Comment: Do you want to run it in Visual Studio or at command prompt?

Comment: @LexLi I want to run my tests in VS

Comment: It is well documented by Microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-a-unit-test-as-a-64-bit-process?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-a-unit-test-as-a-64-bit-process?view=vs-2017 given by Lex Li, I selected Tests in the VS menu, selected Test Settings, selected Default Processor Architecture and changed to x64. After that it worked.

[image]